# LWUIT Form.show() has a weird margin (or padding)

Tags: lwuit, nokia, lwuit-form, nokia-s40

When i add a Form to LWUIT using form.show(), the form is not set exactly in the (0,0) coordinate, it's leaving like 20 pixels in the top and 3 on the left.

I'm developing for the Nokia SDK 1.1 FYI and i'm using their version of LWUIT

Let me know if there is a workaround on this.

Cheers!
Alberto

EDIT:

Here is how i'm creating the Form

```
Display.init(this);
this.view = new Form();
this.view.setLayout(new CoordinateLayout(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight()));
this.view.setScrollableY(false);
this.view.show();
```

This shows a padding on the top and on the left side (Bigger on the top than on the left side)

See a screen shot:

[image: Look at the top margin of the form and left margin of the photo]

Comment: how you are creating it ? write that code so i can have a good idea of your problem.

Comment: Just edited the code so you can take a look Faraz. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the 2 Issues:

1) I had to set the titleArea padding and margins to 0 like this:
this.view.getTitleArea().getStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.view.getTitleArea().getStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.view.revalidate();

2) For the left padding, it was in the label where i was placing the photo, so just changing it's style (padding) to 0 made the trick

Cheers,